# How i use ArrayList<HashMap> of three String type parameters?

Tags: android, string

How can I use ArrayList>
three String member?
I want have

```
String email = do_id.getString("email");
String phone = do_id.getString("phone");
String age = do_id.getString("age");    
map.put("KEY_EMAIL",email);
map.put("KEY_PHONE",phone);
map.put("KEY_age",age); 
getDatalist.add(map);
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? This is a list of invalid hashmaps. Do you want an array list containing three strings? Just do ArrayList<String> and add 3

Comment: i want save more than two string in arraylist

Comment: ArrayList<String> can hold as many strings as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

This's the declaration for Java's [HashMap](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java)

`public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V>`

As you can see it has two type parameters `K` and `V`, you're trying to pass it three which won't work.

You should instead create a data class (POJO) to hold your strings or use a triple (tuple):

```
public final class Triple<L, M, R> {

    private final L left;
    private final M middle;
    private final R right;

    public Triple(L left, M middle, R right) {
        this.left= left;
        this.middle= middle;
        this.right= right;
    }

    public L getLeft() {
        return this.left;
    }

    public M getMiddle() {
        return this.middle;
    }

    public R getRight() {
        return this.right;
    }

    // Android Studio should be able to generate hashCode, equals and toString for you
}


final List<Triple<String, String, String>> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(Triple(email, phone, age));
```

Or you can use apache commons' [Triple](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Triple.html) class